# How to add a new text after every matched string using shell command?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Input:

```
Job name: ns, Job ID: 2312, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL
Job name: ps, Job ID: 3353, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL
Job name: pm, Job ID: 1265, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL
Job name: np, Job ID: 7885, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL
Job name: as, Job ID: 3215, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION UNSUCCESSFUL
```

Output:

```
Job name: ns, Job ID: 2312, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL
Changes has been updated to all servers
Job name: ps, Job ID: 3353, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL
Changes has been updated to all servers
Job name: pm, Job ID: 1265, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL
Changes has been updated to all servers
Job name: np, Job ID: 7885, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL
Changes has been updated to all servers
Job name: as, Job ID: 3215, Status: ODB_ACTIAVTION UNSUCCESSFUL
No change
```

I want to add these text `Changes has been updated to all servers` in every line matched with the string `ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL` and `No change` text after the line matched with the string `ODB_ACTIAVTION UNSUCCESSFUL`.

Comment: Yes but there is some differences... the text what will be added is different and based on two different texts also @don_crissti

Comment: not only the word `ACTIVATION` ... there is two different text ..`ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL` and `ODB_ACTIAVTION UNSUCCESSFUL` @don_crissti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
/ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL/{printf "%s\nChanges has been updated to all servers\n", $0}
/ODB_ACTIAVTION UNSUCCESSFUL/{printf "%s\nNo change\n", $0}
' <in >out
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -e '
  /ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL/a\
  Changes has been updated to all servers
  /ODB_ACTIAVTION UNSUCCESSFUL/a\
  No change
' <in >out
```

Comment: $0 is for new blank line? @cuonglm

Comment: Yes.... both the answers are working... :-) @cuonglm

Comment: @Nainita: No, `$0` is data for `%s` format in `printf`.

Comment: yes... I have already checked... @cuonglm

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/ODB_ACTIAVTION SUCCESSFUL/ {printf "%s\nChanges has been updated to all servers\n", $0}
     /ODB_ACTIAVTION UNSUCCESSFUL/ {printf "%s\nNo change\n", $0}' file1 > file2
```

Comment: yes... it's working perfectly @unxnut